# Three tier architecture issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net project in three tier architecture. I added a Business Access Layer (BAL) and Data Access Layer (DAL) as a class library in the solution and I have added DAL's reference in BAL and BAL's reference in UI.

I have written some methods in one of the classes of BAL and its working fine but now I am adding new methods to any class of BAL ans accessing newly added method in UI. So new added method is not accessible in UI and it s giving me error as

> *'BAL.TaskBAL' does not contain a definition for
>   'deleteSelectedTaskBAL' and no extension method
>   'deleteSelectedTaskBAL' accepting a first argument of type
>   'BAL.TaskBAL' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>
>   D:\Mohsin\CurrentlyWorking\ManageTaskBALDAL\AdminHomePage.aspx.cs*

Here `deleteSelectedBAL` is the newly added method

Comment: As the warning says: `are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Comment: Does your UI reference the BAL project directly or a pre-built dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can try two things

1) delete .dll file from bin of UI folder and then try to add it again.
2) you can set the project dependency by right clicking on the solution. then u r not required to add again and again

Comment: Which solution did you adopted?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the issue in past. Sometimes Cleaning and rebuilding the BAL project helps too.

Also make sure you are using the namespaces in the code file where you are calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace BLL
{
    public class tblSubCategory
    {
        public tblSubCategory()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
        private int iSubCatId;
        private string sSubCatName;
        private string sImagePath;
        private int iCategoryId;
        private string sDescription;
        private decimal decPrice;
        private int sCategoryName;

        public int SubCatId
        {
            get
            { return iSubCatId; }
            set
            { iSubCatId = value; }
        }
        public string SubCatName
        {
            get
            {
                return sSubCatName;
            }
            set
            { sSubCatName = value; }
        }
        public string ImagePath
        {
            get
            {
                return sImagePath;
            }
            set
            { sImagePath = value; }

        }
        public int CategoryId
        {
            get
            {
                return iCategoryId;
            }
            set
            { iCategoryId = value; }
        }
        public string Description
        {
            get
            { return sDescription; }
            set
            { sDescription = value; }
        }
        public decimal Price
        {
            get
            { return decPrice; }
            set
            { decPrice = value; }
        }
        public int CategoryName
        {
            get
            {
                return sCategoryName;
            }
            set
            { sCategoryName = value; }
        }

        public int InserttblSubCategory()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@sSubCatName", sSubCatName);
            db.AddParameter("@sImagePath", sImagePath);
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", iCategoryId);
            db.AddParameter("@sDescription", sDescription);
            db.AddParameter("@decPrice", decPrice);
            return db.ExecuteNonQuery("[tblSubCategory_Insert]", true);
        }
        public DataSet SelectAlltblSubCategory()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            //db.AddParameter("@iSubCatId", iSubCatId);
            //return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_SelectAllForDDL");
            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_SelectAll");
        }
        public int UpdatetblSubCategory()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();

            db.AddParameter("@iSubCatId", iSubCatId);
            db.AddParameter("@sSubCatName", sSubCatName);
            //db.AddParameter("@sImagePath", sImagePath);
            //db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", iCategoryId);
            db.AddParameter("@sDescription", sDescription);
            db.AddParameter("@decPrice", decPrice);
            return db.ExecuteNonQuery("[tblSubCategory_Update]", true);
        }
        public int DeletetblSubCategory()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iSubCatId", iSubCatId);

            return db.ExecuteNonQuery("[tblSubCategory_Delete]", true);
        }
        public DataSet SubCategoryAscByCategory()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", CategoryId);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("[tblSubCategory_SelectAsc]");

        }
        public DataSet SubCategoryDescByCategory()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", CategoryId);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("[tblSubCategory_SelectDescPrice]");

        }
        public DataSet InnerjointblSubCategory1()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", CategoryId);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("[tblSubCategory_InnerJoin1]");

        }
        public DataSet SelectDesctblSubCategory()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", iCategoryId);
            //db.AddParameter("@sSubCatName", sSubCatName);
            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_SelectDesc");
        }
        public DataSet SelectSubCatName()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", iCategoryId);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_SelectSubCatName");
        }
        public DataSet SelectProductsBySubCategory()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iSubCatId", iSubCatId);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblProduct_ProductBySubCat");
        }

        public DataSet selectallsub()
        {

            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            //db.AddParameter("@iSubCatId", iSubCatId);
            //return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_SelectAllForDDL");
            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_InnerJoin2");
        }
        public DataSet selectallsubasc()
        {

            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            //db.AddParameter("@iSubCatId", iSubCatId);
            //return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_SelectAllForDDL");
            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_InnerJoinDesc");
        }
        public DataSet SelectSubCategoryBySubCatId()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iSubCatId", iSubCatId);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_ddlProduct");
        }

        public DataSet SelectSubCategoryByCategory()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", iCategoryId);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_SelectSubCategoryByCategory");
        }
        public DataSet GetSubCategory()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@sSubCatName", sSubCatName);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_SelectSname");
        }
        public DataSet SubCategoryByCatAsc()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", iCategoryId);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_asc");
        }
        public DataSet SubCategoryByCatDesc()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", iCategoryId);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblSubCategory_desc");
        }
        public DataSet CategoryByCatId()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", iCategoryId);

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("tblCategory_SelectAllCat");
        }
        public DataSet InnerjointblSubCategoryTop3()
        {
            DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
            //db.AddParameter("@sCategoryName", CategoryName);
            db.AddParameter("@iCategoryId", CategoryId);
            return db.ExecuteDataSet("[tblSubCategory_InnerJoinTop3]");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: perhaps you should provide some explanation to go with your massive block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the reference to the *project* or to the *assembly* that is a build artifact of the project. If your reference is to the build artificate, then your dependency chain is broken. drop the reference and add a *project reference* instead.